# website Content shift down when user scrolls the page

Tags: javascript, html, css

Hi There's a bug just that shows up just the first time the user scrolls the page
down, the main content gets shift down you can see it here: https://www.mallyear.com/search?q=phone. there's is some code involved:

```
<div id="#adblocker"></div>

<header id="t3-header">
   // code for the header
 </header>

<div id="stckyalias"></div>

 jQuery(function(){
    // Check the initial Poistion of the Sticky Header
    var stickyHeaderTop = jQuery('#t3-header').offset().top;

    jQuery(window).scroll(function(){
            if( jQuery(window).scrollTop() > stickyHeaderTop ) {
                    jQuery('#t3-header').css({position: 'fixed', top: '0px'});
                    jQuery('#stickyalias').css('display', 'block');
            } else {
                    jQuery('#t3-header').css({position: 'static', top: '0px'});
                    jQuery('#stickyalias').css('display', 'none');
            }
    });
 });
```

and some css

```
.t3-header {
background: rgb(68, 136, 255) none repeat scroll 0 0;
height: 66px;
padding-bottom: 0 !important;
padding-top: 8px !important;
position: fixed;
width: 100%;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 0px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
-moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 0px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
box-shadow: 0 1px 1px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
z-index: 999;
transition: all 0.1s ease-in;
```

}

```
#stickyalias {
 display: none;
 height: 66px;
}      

   #adblocker{
      /*transition: all 0.5s ease; */

     height: 80px;
      background-color: #333333;    

     }
```

I don't know what is causing the content to shift down when I scroll down just a bit just the first time. Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 0):

I've take a look on your website and it seem that a HTML div is added when you scroll the page, the HTML div is #t3-mainbody . What #t3-mainbody is for ?

Greetings,

Alexandre.

Comment: I removed the t3-mainbody by making using display:none, but it still shift the content down when I scroll down, what could be the issue?

Comment: I.m currently searching for the answer ;)

Comment: The answer is: when you scroll the navbar position switch between fixed to static. And your div that contain the items have a padding for when the navbar is fixed the content is below the navbar but if you change to position: static, the navbar is now a solid element so the padding doesn't change ;).

Comment: thank you so much for the answer, but Im not sure i follow exactly..would you mind providing an example please?

Comment: I have post another answer with the solution ;)

Comment: works very wellexcept on this page: [link](https://www.mallyear.com/landing) any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

Change the Jquery code to this:

```
jQuery(function(){
   // Check the initial Poistion of the Sticky Header
   var stickyHeaderTop = jQuery('#t3-header').offset().top;

   jQuery(window).scroll(function(){
          if( jQuery(window).scrollTop() > stickyHeaderTop ) {
                jQuery('#t3-header').css({position: 'fixed', top: '0px'});
                jQuery('#stickyalias').css('display', 'block');
           } else {
                jQuery('#t3-header').css({position: 'static', top: '0px'});
                jQuery('#stickyalias').css('display', 'none');
                jQuery)('.t3-sl').css({padding-top: '0'});
           }    
      });
 });
```